# Backbone: how to get authenticated user data

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I am using Backbone and Marionette.

I have a defined User model:

```
Users.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        short_name: '',
        full_name: ''
    }
});
```

I want to easily accessed currently logged in user data in my backbone code.

I am not sure whether to :

1. have a separate Model that inherits from the User Model (Maybe a Users.AuthUser??)

OR

1. add a separate function inside Users.User model instead that returns me an instance of the User model but containing the logged in user data.

I am also not sure how to retrieve the currently logged in user data.

Do i expose the data through an endpoint url like `http://example.com/me` as JSON?

Or somehow the Backbone can access the session data?

Answer (score 1):

It's a general rule of thumb that if the `subclass` has properties/methods that are of no relevance to the parent then it should be subclassed. In my opinion, this is an example of that.

Backbone (simply an MVC JS implementation) is not able to access your session data. So this will need to be available via a REST request.

Comment: do you implement the same thing in your own backbone app?

Comment: Personally in this scenario as i've described above is what I would do. Subclassing would allow me to override things like `defaults` and `validate()`. And yes, I think `/me` is a perfectly valid resource. If you (or somebody else) is to develop a mobile/desktop application next week, your service implementation should not need to change to accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

Data is not shared between models. Unless you need specific function within the user model for authenticated users, it's sufficient to just populate the authenticate use with more data.

The way I do this is in the `fetch()` method, making sure my model communicated with an endpoint that returns a JSON of the currently logged in user.

In order to define a different `urlRoot` for authenticated vs. other users, you'll need to have two separate models.

P.S., actually I use socket.io as the sync protocol instead of REST API, so I just sync using different event names for current user vs. contacts.

Comment: so do you use a different endpoint url for authenticated user? like /me for logged in user and /user/:id for everybody else?

Comment: Correct. Effectively, I treat them as different models from the API perspective, but still use uniform representation within the backbone app.

Comment: In that case, how do you set a different url when you want to fetch AuthUser? Do you use a fetchAuth() function that is different from the normal fetch()?

Comment: Correction: Just reviewed my code and I actually use two models exactly for this reason: so I can assign them a different `urlRoot` property.

Comment: then do you subclass one model from the other like what @juco suggested?

Comment: In my case, I don't gain anything from subclassing since my models don't include user-specific functions that I might like to inherit.